# How to continue test when the page still not completely loaded in selenium

Tags: selenium

Actually, I am creating automation testing for an e-commerce website. Actually, the website have function lazy load or something. I am testing it on UAT server. So, it will load the page slowly because the specification of the server. It takes more than 60 sec or more to load all the resources from the webpage. So, when I am trying to create selenium automation, it always waiting more than 60 sec to continue the next step (because waiting the page fully loaded). Please, someone give me tips how to continue run the test step after 10 seconds wait the page to load. It won't throw an exception, just continue the test step.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible.

If you find some element and try execute some action while loading you will get `stale element` error + due loading issue you will have a lot of failed tests and it will take a lot more time to debug.

Automation means to ***execute fast***  and ***have reliable results***.
It seems that this environment is not built for automation, you should request more resources.

As an alternative maybe you can use a headless driver or see if you can put the same build on a VM.

**Why this is an issue**: Selenium needs to wait for each request to be complete.For example when you request a page, if the page is not received entirely and the server still sending info then the request is not done, it is logical that you need a complete request in order to continue.

You should address this to your Project Manager/QA Lead and ask for advice/option on how to handle this.
Please note that these costs should be included/added in the automation price.You need to address this in a simple way:

- good server -> automation runs smoothly and fast and the testing is
  done faster
- bad server -> unable to run automation since is not reliable and each
  test has a high rate of failure => alternative ***X*** day(s) of
  manual testing for each build

If this would be a coding issue like some delayed ajax request then you would have some solutions, devs could help, but if is an infrastructure/resources issue then if not depending on you, and you cannot solve it.
You could use try any type of wait implicit/explicit, explicit would throw some exception, but this is not a solution for poor resources.

Comment: actually IDK why my automation is like waiting forever. the page and the element already loaded. but something makes the automation wait forever. so I need to give timeouts and continue the test. if the element that I wan't to test is not properly loaded, it is OK if it will giving error.

Comment: is it possible for using implicit wait?